# how to implement the arrow alert thing on the notification on instagram

Tags: android, ios, react-native

How can I implement this on my app im using react native? or what is it called? Photo for reference. Thank you!!

[image]

Comment: it looks like a custom view: you need to build it by yourself

Comment: how can I show it above of bottom tab? @kingston